# How to make Vala available in my NetBeans IDE for autocomplete or What else can be used for Vala to have autocompletes?

Tags: c, netbeans, ide, netbeans-plugins, vala

I just ran this code, and it looks like nice language for me.

But when i was trying in NetBeans IDE i do not see any Vala nor i see any autocomplete availability.

Any idea how to make NetBeans IDE to allow Vala? (to get auto-complete specially)

e.g:

```
using Gtk;

int main (string[] args) 
{
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    var window = new Window ();
    window.title = "First GTK+ Program";
    window.border_width = 10;
    window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size (350, 70);
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

    var button = new Button.with_label ("Click me!");
    button.clicked.connect (() => {
        button.label = "Thank you";
    });

    window.add (button);
    window.show_all ();

    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried from here: https://github.com/carbonfx/netbeans-valaproject/downloads
But does not work.

[image]

**Follow up:**

> NetBeans IDE i could not make it someone can update it later!
>
> I installed Anjuta IDE using yum -y install anjuta, and simply Vala works
>   [image]
>
> I will try this too: http://yorba.org/valencia/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Anjuta IDE](http://www.anjuta.org/), or turn Gedit into a Vala IDE using [Valencia](http://yorba.org/valencia/).

Comment: Thanks, NetBeans did not worked. Anjuta worked but its so big in font size etc not looks like NetBeans. Valencia i have to compile?

Comment: You can change the font size in Anjuta using the preferences. Check to see if your distribution has a package for Valencia, otherwise you will have to compile it.